# Justification for using $A+B+C=1$ as a constraint of the equation for a quadric surface resulting in an ellipsoid?

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections, least-squares

In an answer to this [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568368/help-with-least-squares-ellipsoid-specific-fitting/4568496?noredirect=1#comment9623458_4568496), the constraint $A+B+C=1$ is used in the equation for an origin-centered quadric surface, Eq(1), in the development of the least-squares minimization that will result in an ellipsoid.

$$\tag{1} A x^2 + B y^2 + C z^2 + D xy + E xz + F yz  + G = 0 $$

The purpose of this post is to ask **why and how the constraint $A+B+C=1$ is justified for use to constrain the least-squares minimization problem described in the [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568368/help-with-least-squares-ellipsoid-specific-fitting/4568496?noredirect=1#comment9623458_4568496)? From where does this constraint $A+B+C=1$ originate?**

Some thoughts I have that may link the constraint $A+B+C=1$ to an ellipsoid are:

- the equation for an axis-aligned ellipsoid in 'standard form' is $$\tag{2} \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$ where $x,y,z$ are the cartesian coordinates of some dataset of points $\{ P_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i) , i = 1, N\}$. In 'quadric form', Eq(2) is $$\tag{3} Ax^2+By^2+Cz^2=1$$
  where $A=1/a^2, B=1/b^2, C=1/c^2$. Thus, the values for $a,b,c$ in Eq(2) are equivalent to $a=\sqrt{1/A}; b=\sqrt{1/B}; c=\sqrt{1/C}$.
- The set of points $P_i$ will have components $x_i,y_i,z_i$ that are all real numbers (I believe this is notated as $(x_i, y_i, z_i) \in \Bbb R^3$). The magnitude of the position vector $\vec r$ for these points is $$\tag{4} |\vec r| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ and thus always a positive value ($\ge 0$).
- A non-axis-aligned ellipsoid is given by the equation $$\tag{5} \mathbf{r}^T Q \mathbf{r} = 1$$ where

$Q = \begin{bmatrix} A && D / 2 && E / 2 \\ D / 2 && B && F/2 \\ E/2 && F/2 && C \end{bmatrix}$

and

$r = [x, y, z]^T$

For an ellipsoid, the matrix $Q$ is always positive definite. I think positive definite means the diagonal coefficients $A,B,C$ of matrix $Q$ must be $>0$.

Comment: I am worried by the fact that you think positive means $\geqslant 0$; surely it means $>0$? Then positive definite forces $A,B,C>0$ so that we can scale by $A+B+C$ with no difficulty.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I will edit to correct. positive semidefinite for $\ge 0$, yes?

Comment: @ancientmathematician And what you say makes sense (if I am thinking about this correctly), if any of the values $A,B,C$ were to be equal to $0$, then we wouldn't have an ellipsoid!

Comment: If it is an ellipsoid then wrt some set of orthogonal axes we have that the equation is $aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2=1$ where $a,b,c>0$. Then for any non-zero point the LHS $>0$. In the original coords the LHS is $A$ at $(1,0,0)$ so $A>0$ so, yes.

Comment: @ancientmathematician (+1) if $aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2=1$ where $a,b,c>0$, then for any non-zero point the LHS $=1$, no? (Which is $>0$, but specifically, it is $=1$. But maybe I'm not seeing something, the point being made).

Comment: We have $f(x,y,z)=\mathbf{x}^TA \mathbf{x}$ for a symmetric matrix. The surface $f=1$ is an ellipsoid if there is an orthogonal change of axis $\mathbf{x}=\Omega \mathbf{X}$ such that $f=aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2$ with $a,b,c>0$. That implies that the function $f$ is positive definite, meaning that $f\geqslant 0$ always and $f=0$ only at the origin $(0,0,0)$. But now in the original coords look at the point $(1,0,0)$: $f(1,0,0)=A$ and so $A>0$